# enable footer appear below z-index controlled divs

Tags: html, css

As seen in my [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1263/) I'm enabling two divs whose inner HTML is populated by JS appear over each other based on either full-width styling or media query styling but I'm unable to set my two footers to appear below the divs which appear on top of each other.

To enable them appear on top of each other I'm using position: absolute and a z-index value for both divs.

Any ideas as to how I could enable my footers to appear below the divs whilst the browser is resized

Really appreciate any help.

EDIT: I've updated my code and fidlle ... In the CSS I removed position: absolute; from #divcalendartabletwo which enables both footers to appear below the calendar but this slightly messes up my media query when I load up the page in portrait mode on an iphone .. basically my elements are not taking up the full width of the sciphone screen

HTML:

```
    <!-- JS targets this div -->
    <div class="overalldivcalendartable">

       <!-- <div id="year"></div> -->

      <div class="controlsdivcalendartable">
           <span id="btnPrevYr" title="Previous Year"><span><<</span></span>

           <span id="btnPrev" title="Previous Month"><span><</span></span>

           <!-- <input type="button" src="images/btnprevmonth.png" alt="Submit" id="btnPrev"/>-->

           <!-- <div id="month"></div> -->

             <!-- JS targets this div -->
             <div id="monthandyear"></div>

           <!--<input type="button" src="images/btnnextmonth.png" alt="Submit" id="btnNext"/>-->

           <span id="btnNext" title="Next Month"><span>></span></span>

           <span id="btnNextYr" title="Next Year"><span>>></span></span>      
        </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div id="divcalendartable"></div>

    <div id="divcalendartabletwo"></div>         

    </div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<footer id="footer">
    <section>
        <h3>ABOUT US:</h3>

        <p>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. <br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. <br></p>             
    </section>

    <section>
        <h3>LIKE, FOLLOW OR WATCH US:</h3>
        <ul class="social">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/facebook.png"/></a></li>               
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/twitter1.png"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/youtube.png"/></a></li>                    
        </ul>
    </section>

    <section id="contactus">
        <h3>CONTACT US:</h3>

        <p>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..<br><br><b>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..</b><br><br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..<br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..</p>             
    </section>
</footer>

<footer class="footerTwo">
    <p> Copyright &copy; 2015 | qwerty Ltd | All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

footer p, footer h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

footer p a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}

ul.social li {
    display: inline;
}

ul.social img {
    height: 50px;
}

footer.footerTwo {
    border-top: 1px solid #4D4350;
    background-color: #3366FF;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Generic table styling */
.overalldivcalendartable {
    margin: 12px 0 12px 10px;
    float: left;
}

.controlsdivcalendartable {
    background: #FFCC00;
    float: left;
}

table { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}

th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold; 
  padding: 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

td { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Disable div to be used for media query calendar */
#divcalendartable {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}

#divcalendartabletwo {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

#divcalendartable, #divcalendartabletwo {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#btnPrevYr, #btnPrev, #monthandyear, #btnNext, #btnNextYr {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    /*background: #00FFCC;*/      
}

#monthandyearspan {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*background: #00FFCC;*/
}   

#monthandyear {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}

.daysheader {
  background: #C0C0C0;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#prevmonthdates, #nextmonthdates {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
}

#prevmonthdates, #nextmonthdates {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#currentmonthdates {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
}

/*Apply styling UL cellvaluelist*/
#cellvaluelist {
  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;  
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*Apply styling on all LI items in the UL cellvaluelist*/
#cellvaluelist > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
}

/*Eliminate border on last list item*/
#cellvaluelist > li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

/*Styling for the span in the main list*/
#cellvaluelist > li span {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;

  -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
}

/*Shared styling for swim and chrono*/
.swim, .chrono {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal; 
}

/*Styling for the list items in the table cells*/
.swim {
  background: #626FD1;
}

/*Hover on the 1st LI item on the list in the table cell*/
.swim:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Styling for the list items in the table cells*/
.chrono {
    background: #EDCF47;
}

/*Hover on the 2nd LI item on the list in the table cell*/
.chrono:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Styling for the list items in the table cells*/
.couponcode {
    background: #47ED4D;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/*Hover on the last LI item on the list in the table cell*/
.couponcode:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Apply the hover on the UL coupontooltipullist*/
.couponcode:hover .coupontooltipullist {
    display: block;
}

/*UL in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltipullist {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px;
}

/*Shared UL and LI list properties in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltipullist, .coupontooltip_li_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

/*LI in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltip_li_list {
    background: #D6D6D6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
    padding: 10px;
 }

/*IMG in the LI in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltipimg {
    width: 55px;
    height: 48px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;    
}

/*Span in the LI in the tooltip*/
.coupontooltiplistspan {
  float: right;
}

/*Responsive Styles - div_lhs_menu and table */
@media screen and (max-width : 768px), screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)  {

    .div_lhs_menu {
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .overalldivcalendartable {
       clear: both;
       margin-top: 10px;
       margin-left: 0px;
    }

    #divcalendartable {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #divcalendartabletwo {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    #btnPrevYr, #btnPrev, #monthandyear, #btnNext, #btnNextYr {
        margin-left: 7px;
        margin-right: 7px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #monthandyearspan {
      margin-left: 7px;
      margin-right: 7px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    #prevmonthdates, #currentmonthdates, #nextmonthdates {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }      
}

@media screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
    .overalldivcalendartable {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width : 1185px) {
    .overalldivcalendartable {
        width: 75%;
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all remove `position:absolute` from `#divcalendartabletwo {` .

Comment: hi ketan .. thanks .. I've removed the position:absolute  and this works for the footer with id="footer" but not the othyer footer class="footerTwo" ...

Comment: Will you post your updated code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `position:absolute` from `#divcalendartabletwo` and **footer** It will solved your issue.

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1262/)

```js
var Calendar = function(o) {
        this.divId = o.ParentID;

        this.DaysOfWeek = o.DaysOfWeek;

        myLogger("this.DaysOfWeek == " + this.DaysOfWeek)

        this.Months = o.Months;

        myLogger("this.Months == " + this.Months)

        var d = new Date();

        myLogger("d == " + d)

        this.CurrentMonth = d.getMonth();

        myLogger("this.CurrentMonth == " + this.CurrentMonth);

        this.CurrentYear = d.getFullYear();

        myLogger("this.CurrentYear == "+ this.CurrentYear);

        var f=o.Format;

        myLogger("o == " + o);

        myLogger("f == " + f);


        if(typeof(f) == 'string') {
          this.f  = f.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        } else {
          this.f = 'M';
        }

        console.log("this.f == ", this.f);
      };

      Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
        console.log("Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {");

        if ( this.CurrentMonth == 11 ) {
          console.log("this.CurrentMonth == " + this.CurrentMonth);

          this.CurrentMonth = 0;

          console.log("this.CurrentMonth == " + this.CurrentMonth);

          console.log("this.CurrentYear == "+ this.CurrentYear);

          this.CurrentYear = this.CurrentYear + 1;

          console.log("this.CurrentYear == "+ this.CurrentYear);
        } else {
          console.log("this.CurrentMonth == " + this.CurrentMonth);

          this.CurrentMonth = this.CurrentMonth + 1;

          console.log("this.CurrentMonth + 1 == " + this.CurrentMonth);
        }

        this.showCurrent();
      };

      Calendar.prototype.previousMonth = function() {
        console.log("Calendar.prototype.previousMonth = function() {");

        if ( this.CurrentMonth == 0 ) {
          console.log("this.CurrentMonth == " + this.CurrentMonth);

          this.CurrentMonth = 11;

          console.log("this.CurrentMonth == " + this.CurrentMonth);

          console.log("this.CurrentYear == "+ this.CurrentYear);

          this.CurrentYear = this.CurrentYear - 1;

          console.log("this.CurrentYear == "+ this.CurrentYear);
        } else {
          console.log("this.CurrentMonth == " + this.CurrentMonth);

          this.CurrentMonth = this.CurrentMonth - 1;

          console.log("this.CurrentMonth - 1 == " + this.CurrentMonth);
        }

        this.showCurrent();
      };

      Calendar.prototype.previousYear = function() {
        console.log(" ");

        console.log("Calendar.prototype.previousYear = function() {");

        console.log("this.CurrentYear == " + this.CurrentYear);

        this.CurrentYear = this.CurrentYear - 1;

        console.log("this.CurrentYear - 1 i.e. this.CurrentYear == " + this.CurrentYear);

        this.showCurrent();
      }

      Calendar.prototype.nextYear = function() {
        console.log(" ");

        console.log("Calendar.prototype.nextYear = function() {");

        console.log("this.CurrentYear == " + this.CurrentYear);

        this.CurrentYear = this.CurrentYear + 1;

        console.log("this.CurrentYear - 1 i.e. this.CurrentYear == " + this.CurrentYear);

        this.showCurrent();
      }             

      Calendar.prototype.showCurrent = function() {
        console.log(" ");

        console.log("Calendar.prototype.showCurrent = function() {");

        console.log("this.CurrentYear == "+ this.CurrentYear);

        console.log("this.CurrentMonth == " + this.CurrentMonth);

        this.Calendar(this.CurrentYear, this.CurrentMonth);
      };

      Calendar.prototype.Calendar = function(y,m) {
        console.log(" ");

        console.log("Calendar.prototype.Calendar = function(y,m){");

        typeof(y) == 'number' ? this.CurrentYear = y : null;

        console.log("this.CurrentYear == "+ this.CurrentYear);

        typeof(y) == 'number' ? this.CurrentMonth = m : null;

        console.log("this.CurrentMonth == " + this.CurrentMonth);

        var firstDayOfCurrentMonth = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay();

        console.log("firstDayOfCurrentMonth == ", firstDayOfCurrentMonth);

        var lastDateOfCurrentMonth = new Date(y, m+1, 0).getDate();

        console.log("lastDateOfCurrentMonth == ", lastDateOfCurrentMonth);

        console.log("m == ", m);

        var lastDateOfLastMonth = m == 0 ? new Date(y-1, 11, 0).getDate() : new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();

        console.log("lastDateOfLastMonth == ", lastDateOfLastMonth);

        console.log("Print selected month and year.");

        
        var monthandyearhtml = '<span id="monthandyearspan">' + this.Months[m] + ' - ' + y + '</span>';

        console.log("monthandyearhtml == " + monthandyearhtml);

        var html = '<table>';

        var htmltwo = '<table>';

        html += '<tr>';

        htmltwo += '<tr>'; 

        console.log(" ");

        console.log("Write the header of the days of the week");

        for(var i=0; i < 7;i++) {
          console.log("i == ", i);

          console.log("this.DaysOfWeek[i] == ", this.DaysOfWeek[i]);

          html += '<th class="daysheader">' + this.DaysOfWeek[i] + '</th>';

          htmltwo += '<th class="daysheader">' + this.DaysOfWeek[i] + '</th>';
        }

        html += '</tr>';

        htmltwo += '</tr>';

        console.log("Before conditional operator this.f == ", this.f);


        var p = dm = this.f == 'M' ? 1 : firstDayOfCurrentMonth == 0 ? -5 : 2;

       
        console.log("After conditional operator");

        console.log("this.f == ", this.f);

        console.log("p == ", p);

        console.log("dm == ", dm);

        console.log("firstDayOfCurrentMonth == ", firstDayOfCurrentMonth);

        var cellvalue;

        for (var d, i=0, z0=0; z0<6; z0++) {
          html += '<tr>';

          htmltwo += '<tr>';

          console.log("Inside 1st for loop - d == " + d + " | i == " + i + " | z0 == " + z0);

          for (var z0a = 0; z0a < 7; z0a++) {
            console.log("Inside 2nd for loop");

            console.log("z0a == " + z0a);

            d = i + dm - firstDayOfCurrentMonth;

            console.log("d outside if statm == " + d);

              console.log("d < 1");

              console.log("p before p++ == " + p);

              cellvalue = lastDateOfLastMonth - firstDayOfCurrentMonth + p++;

              console.log("p after p++ == " + p);

              console.log("cellvalue == " + cellvalue);

              html += '<td id="prevmonthdates">' + 
                      '<span id="cellvaluespan">' + (cellvalue) + '</span><br/>' +

                   '<ul class="cellvaluelist">' + 
                               '<li><span href="#" class="swim">SWIM - 1500m</span></li>' +

                              '<li><span href="#" class="chrono">CHRONO - 1500m</span></li>' +

                               '<li><span href="#" class="couponcode">MORE' +

                                   '<ul class="coupontooltipullist">' +

                                    '<li class="coupontooltip_li_list">' +
                                     '<img class="coupontooltipimg" src="images/tooltipswim.png">' + 
                                     '<span class="coupontooltiplistspan">Distance: 200m</br>Duration: 00:01:30</br>Laps: 4</span>' +
                                    '</li></br>' +

                                    '<li class="coupontooltip_li_list">' +
                                     '<img class="coupontooltipimg" src="images/tooltipswim.png">' + 
                                     '<span class="coupontooltiplistspan">Distance: 200m</br>Duration: 00:01:30</br>Laps: 4</span>' +
                                    '</li></br>' +                                

                                   '</ul>' +
                                   '</span>' + 
                              '</li>' +
                       '</ul>' +
                       '</td>';

              htmltwo += '<td id="prevmonthdates">' + 
                        '<span id="cellvaluespan">' + (cellvalue) + '</span><br/>' +

                        '<ul class="cellvaluelist">' + 
                                 '<li><span href="#" class="swim">SW</span></li>' +

                                 '<li><span href="#" class="chrono">CH</span></li>' +

                                 '<li><span href="#" class="couponcode">M' +

                                      '<ul class="coupontooltipullist">' +                                  

                                      '</ul>' +

                                      '</span>' + 
                                 '</li>' +
                        '</ul>' +
                       '</td>';

            } else if ( d > lastDateOfCurrentMonth){
              console.log("d > lastDateOfCurrentMonth");

              console.log("p before p++ == " + p);

              html += '<td id="nextmonthdates">' + (p++) + '</td>';

              htmltwo += '<td id="nextmonthdates">' + (p++) + '</td>';

              console.log("p after p++ == " + p);

            } else {
              html += '<td id="currentmonthdates">' + (d) + '</td>';
              
              htmltwo += '<td id="currentmonthdates">' + (d) + '</td>';

              console.log("d inside else { == " + d);

              p = 1;

              console.log("p inside } else { == " + p);
            }
            
            if (i % 7 == 6 && d >= lastDateOfCurrentMonth) {
              console.log("INSIDE if (i % 7 == 6 && d >= lastDateOfCurrentMonth) {");

              console.log("i == " + i);

              console.log("d == " + d);

              console.log("z0 == " + z0);

              z0 = 10; 
            }

            console.log("i before i++ == " + i);

            i++;

            console.log("i after i++ == " + i);           
          }

          html += '</tr>';

          htmltwo += '</tr>';
        }

        html += '</table>';

        htmltwo += '</table>';


        document.getElementById("monthandyear").innerHTML = monthandyearhtml;

        document.getElementById(this.divId).innerHTML = html;

        document.getElementById("divcalendartabletwo").innerHTML = htmltwo;
      };

      window.onload = function() {
        
        var c = new Calendar({
          ParentID:"divcalendartable",

          DaysOfWeek:[
          'MON',
          'TUE',
          'WED',
          'THU',
          'FRI',
          'SAT',
          'SUN'
          ],

          Months:['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ],

          Format:'dd/mm/yyyy'
        });

        c.showCurrent();
        
        getId('btnPrev').onclick = function(){
          c.previousMonth();
        };

        getId('btnPrevYr').onclick = function(){
          c.previousYear();
        };

        getId('btnNext').onclick = function(){
          c.nextMonth();
        };

        getId('btnNextYr').onclick = function(){
          c.nextYear();
        };                        
      }

      function getId(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
      }

      function myLogger(content) {
       if (window.console && window.console.log) {
           console.log(content);
       }
     }
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background: #F5F5F5;
 color: #363636;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 20px; 
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 100%;
 line-height: 120%;
 padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

h2 {
 line-height: 280%;
 padding-left: 3%;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

h3 {
 line-height: 120%;
 padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

p {
 padding: 1%;
}

img {
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
}

a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px; 
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}

header {
 background-color: #3366FF;
 width: 100%;
 height: 86px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 opacity: 0.90%;
}

#logo {
 margin: 0px;
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 86px;
 background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat center;
}

nav {
 float: right;
 padding: 25px 20px 20px 0;
}

#menu-icon {
 display: hidden;
 width: 100px;
 height: 86px;
 background: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png);
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
} 

a:hover#menu-icon {
 border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #363636;
 text-decoration: none;
}

section {
 width: 29%;
 float: left;
 margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
 text-align: center;
}

.clear {
 clear: both;
}

#genericlinkdecoration {
 color: #3366FF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 14px;
}

footer {
 background-color: #808080;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

footer p, footer h3 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

footer p a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 14px;
}

ul.social li {
 display: inline;
}

ul.social img {
 height: 50px;
}

footer.footerTwo {
 border-top: 1px solid #4D4350;
 background-color: #3366FF;
 text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px), screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)  {
 body {
  position: absolute;
 }

 header {
  position: absolute;
 }

 #menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
 } 

 nav {
  padding: 0;
 }

 nav ul, nav:active ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
  right: 20px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 2px;
 }

 nav:hover ul {
  display: block;
 }

 nav ul li a {
  color: #363636;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #3366FF;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 nav li {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
 }

 section {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }        
}

.horizontalmenubar {
 margin-top: 86px;
 background: #D6D6D6;
 height: 50px;
}

.horizontalmenubar ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.horizontalmenubar li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 0px;
 width: 200px;
 border-right: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.horizontalmenubar li a {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 color: #000000;
 background: #D6D6D6;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.horizontalmenubar li:hover a {
 background: #F5F5F5;
 color: #3366FF;
}

.horizontalmenubar li ul {
 display: none;
}

.horizontalmenubar li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
}

.horizontalmenubar li ul li a {
 padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
 line-height: 25px; 
}

.horizontalmenubar li:hover ul li a {
 background: #D6D6D6;
 color: #000000; 
}

.horizontalmenubar li ul li a:hover {
 background: #F5F5F5;
 color: #3366FF; 
}

.horizontalmenubar ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}

.show-menu {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 background: #D6D6D6;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.horizontalmenubar input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

.horizontalmenubar input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 768px), screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)  {

 .horizontalmenubar ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
 }

 .horizontalmenubar li {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
 }

 .horizontalmenubar ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;
 }

 .show-menu {
  display:block;
 }
}

.maindiv {
 width: 100%;
 background: #FFCC00;
}

.div_lhs_menu {
 margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
 float: left;
}

.js-css-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

.js-css-menu, .js-css-menu ul, .js-css-menu li {
  list-style: none; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}

.js-css-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.js-css-menu > li {
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: #D6D6D6;
}

.js-css-menu > li > a {
  color: #000000; 
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.js-css-menu > li:hover > a {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  color: #3366FF;
}

.js-css-menu > li div {
  position: absolute; 
  display: none;
  background: #D6D6D6;
}

.js-css-menu > li:hover div {
  display: block;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul {
  float: none;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul li {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.js-css-menu > li div ul li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #407D94; 
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li {
  display: block; 
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div {
  width: 150px; 
  top: 0;
  left: 181px;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #407D94;
}

.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li a {
  color: #555;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 768px), screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)  {

 
 .js-css-menu.vertical {
   width: 100%; 
 }
}

.overalldivcalendartable {
 margin: 12px 0 12px 10px;
 float: left;
}

.controlsdivcalendartable {
 background: #FFCC00;
 float: left;
}

table { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}

th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold; 
  padding: 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

td { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#divcalendartable {
 visibility: visible;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
}

#divcalendartabletwo {
 visibility: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}

#divcalendartable, #divcalendartabletwo {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#btnPrevYr, #btnPrev, #monthandyear, #btnNext, #btnNextYr {
 font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   cursor: pointer;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-right: 20px;
}

#monthandyearspan {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}   

#monthandyear {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}

.daysheader {
  background: #C0C0C0;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#prevmonthdates, #nextmonthdates {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
}

#prevmonthdates, #nextmonthdates {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#currentmonthdates {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
}

#cellvaluelist {
  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;  
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#cellvaluelist > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
}

#cellvaluelist > li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

#cellvaluelist > li span {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
 
  -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.swim, .chrono {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal; 
}

.swim {
  background: #626FD1;
}

.swim:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chrono {
    background: #EDCF47;
}

.chrono:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.couponcode {
    background: #47ED4D;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.couponcode:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.couponcode:hover .coupontooltipullist {
    display: block;
}

.coupontooltipullist {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px;
}

.coupontooltipullist, .coupontooltip_li_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.coupontooltip_li_list {
    background: #D6D6D6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
    padding: 10px;
 }

.coupontooltipimg {
    width: 55px;
    height: 48px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;    
}

.coupontooltiplistspan {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 768px), screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)  {

 .div_lhs_menu {
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .overalldivcalendartable {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
 }

 #divcalendartable {
  visibility: hidden;
 }

 #divcalendartabletwo {
  visibility: visible;
 }

 #btnPrevYr, #btnPrev, #monthandyear, #btnNext, #btnNextYr {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
 }

 #monthandyearspan {
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
 }

 #prevmonthdates, #currentmonthdates, #nextmonthdates {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   font-size: 20px;
 }    
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" id="logo"></a>

  <nav>
   <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>

   <ul>
    <li><a href="#containerjoin">My Profile</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#containerjoin">Log Out</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Help and FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>    
  </nav>    
 </header>

 <div class="clear"></div>

 <div class="horizontalmenubar">

  <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">MAIN MENU</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">

  <ul id="menu"> 

   <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a>
    
   </li>
  
   <li>
    <a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
    
   </li>

   <li>
    <a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
    
   </li>

   <li><a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a></li>

   <li><a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="clear"></div>

 <div class="maindiv">
     <div class="div_lhs_menu">

      <ul class="js-css-menu responsive vertical">
        <li><a href="#overalldivcalendartable">Calendar</a>
       </li>
        
        <li><a href="#">Dboard option 2</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Dboard option 3</a>
         
        </li>
      </ul>

     </div>

  <div class="overalldivcalendartable">


       <div class="controlsdivcalendartable">
           <span id="btnPrevYr" title="Previous Year"><span></span></span>

           <span id="btnPrev" title="Previous Month"><span></span></span>

          <div id="monthandyear"></div>


           <span id="btnNext" title="Next Month"><span>></span></span>
            
           <span id="btnNextYr" title="Next Year"><span>>></span></span>      
      </div>

       <div class="clear"></div>

       <div id="divcalendartable"></div>

        <div id="divcalendartabletwo"></div>         

  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="clear"></div>

 <footer id="footer">
  <section>
   <h3>ABOUT US:</h3>

   <p>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..  <br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..  qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. <br></p>    
  </section>

  <section>
   <h3>LIKE, FOLLOW OR WATCH US:</h3>
   <ul class="social">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/facebook.png"/></a></li>    
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/twitter1.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/youtube.png"/></a></li>     
   </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="contactus">
   <h3>CONTACT US:</h3>

   <p>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..</b><br><br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..<br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..</p>    
  </section>
 </footer>

 <footer class="footerTwo">
  <p> Copyright &copy; 2015 | qwerty Ltd | All rights reserved.</p>
 </footer>
```